# sending output of a c++ program into a variable bash

Tags: c++, bash

I'm trying to write a system that grades a c++ code with pre-written examples that i have ready. It's a very simple c++ code like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    if (a > 100)
        cout << "Big";
    else
        cout << "Small";
    return 0;
}
```

So i want to test and grade this program with a bash, declare a **score** variable and echo it in the end. Here's what i wrote(I've marked where i need help writing with double quotes)

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ new.cpp -o new
test1=101
test2=78
score=0
if [ "Result of executing ./new with $test1 variable as input"=="Big" ]
then
(( score += 50 ))
fi
if [ "Result of executing ./new with $test2 variable as input"=="Small" ]
then
(( score += 50 ))
fi
echo $score
```

Also i'm still very new to bash so if you can tell me a simpler way to use bash for the examples (like loops) i'd love to hear it.
Thanks!

Comment: IMHO, using a temporary file would be easier.  Your C++ program should write to a temporary file that your `bash` script can read.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `if [ "Result of executing ./new with $test1 variable as input"=="Big" ]` is always true, since `Result of executing ./new with $test 1 variable as input==Big` is a non-empty string.  `[` is a fickle beast.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute **new** with the params and get its result, you should try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ new.cpp -o new
test1=101
test2=78
score=0
if [ $(./new $test1) == "Big" ]; then
    (( score += 50 ))
fi
if [ $(./new $test2) == "Small" ]; then
    (( score += 50 ))
fi
echo $score
```

Comment: You should quote the command substitution `$()` within `[ ]`, or the script breaks if the output of `new` contains spaces; the output will also be subject to glob expansion if unquoted.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `[[ ]]`, which does the quoting for you. `==` is a Bashism anyway, so why not use other Bash tools as well.